# How to run OCI in linux

Tags: c++, c, oracle, oracle-call-interface, occi

Need to communicate my C code to Oracle 11g. I figure out oci is appropriate. and I don't know how to install it.

on
**`Linux kernel-2.6.32-279.el6.i686`**

I used this code in hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<oci.h> 
int main(void) 
{
      int x;  
      printf("Please Enter Number: ");  
      scanf("%d",&x);  


return 0; 
}
```

and command

```
gcc hello.c -o hello.o
```

Error message displayed:

```
error: oci.h: No such file or directory
```

and Instant client is installed in location

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/instantclient/
```

I know it's basic but me newbie too.

Answer (score 3):

To build OCI applications, you need the SDK, which includes the header files etc. The SDK is included with the Full client and the database; since you're using the Instant client, you need an additional download - see [the official Oracle Instant Client page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html) for download links.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't install Oracle g11 on you system. This [link](http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/howto-install-oracle-11g-ubuntu-linux-1204-precise-pangolin-64bits) may helps you.

Comment: Oracle is installed on another server, Need to run c code with header file oci.h or occi.h, Also where to find these headers. I don't have currently